# AWS Site-to-Site VPN(Virtual IDC VPC and AWS VPC) Network problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn

I have a problem about AWS Site-to-Site VPN network flows.

This is my Network diagram :
[image]

I did Ping protocol test.

1. I sent ping protocol from IDC-EC2 in IDC Private Subnet  to IDC-CGW EC2 in IDC Public Subnet.
   It worked.
2. I sent ping protocol from IDC-EC2 in IDC-CGW EC2 in IDC Public Subnet to AWS-EC2 in AWS Public Subnet. It worked.
3. But I sent ping protocol from IDC-EC2 in IDC Private Subnet to AWS-EC2 in AWS Public Subnet.
   It didn't work.

Please answer my questions.
Thanks!

Comment: If the destination EC2 is in a public subnet, why do you require a VPN connection? And, if you don't want to go via the Internet, have you considered **VPC Peering** instead of a VPN connection?

Comment: Yes, I know but I'm testing AWS VPN,, So, In this Network diagram, I want to find problems

Comment: Ping is not often a good way to test things in AWS because it needs ICMP in the Security Groups and all it does it test whether Ping is working. It is often better to test the connection that you _actually_ want working (eg SSH or HTTP). What is the Security Group on the EC2 instance on the right? What do you mean by "IDC-EC2 in IDC-CGW EC2" (in #2)?